# Why does gcc produce a different result when bulding from source compared to linking a static library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a single C++14 file, `my.cpp`, and from within it I'm trying to use a C99 library called *open62541*. For the latter, both full source `open62541.c/.h` and a library `libopen62541.a` exist. In `my.cpp`, where I include the `open62541.h`, I'm using C++ specific code (e.g. iostream), so technically I'm mixing C and C++.

I can get `my.cpp` to compile successfully by referencing the `libopen62541.a`:

```
gcc -x c++ -std=c++14 -Wall my.cpp -l:libopen62541.a -lstdc++ -o out
```

This outputs no warnings, and creates an executable *out*.

However, if I try to compile using source code only:

```
gcc -x c++ -std=c++14 -Wall my.cpp open62541.c -lstdc++ -o out
```

I get a lot of ISO C++ warnings (e.g. "*ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*'*") and some "*jump to label*" errors originating from within `open62541.c`, resulting in compilation failure.

I can get compilation to succeed by using the `-fpermissive` switch:

```
gcc -x c++ -std=c++14 -Wall my.cpp open62541.c -lstdc++ -fpermissive -o out
```

which still outputs a lot of warnings, but creates the executable successfully. However, I'm unsure if doing this is a good idea.

Perhaps worth mentioning is that `open62541.h` considers C++ at the beginning:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

1. Given that .a library, which comes bundled with the *open62541* library code, is supposedly built from the same source, why are the first two approaches not consistent in terms of warnings and errors generated? Why does one work and the other doesn't?
2. Should one method - linking .a vs referring to .c - be preferred to another? I was under impression that they should be equivalent, but apparently they aren't.
3. Is using `-fpermissive` in this case more of a hack that could mask potential problems, and should thus be avoided?

Comment: You are compiling a `C` program and telling gcc to compile as if it was a `C++` program (`-x c++`).  They are different languages.

Comment: Needing `-fpermissive` is alywas *extremely* dodgy. You code is certainly not standard C++ and *probably* broken. Fixing all the underlying issues causing the warning to occur would be the real solution. Also, note that C is not a subset of C++ and thus not all C code can be compiles as C++.

Comment: I understand the difference between C and C++. What I don't understand is if there is a proper way to get this to mix with gcc? Mixing C and C++ is not unheard of as long as conditions are met (which in this case should be, with extern C etc.), I believe?

Comment: @w128 `extern "C"` is not a silver bullet that somehow makes C-only language features standard C++.

Comment: @BaummitAugen of course, and gcc doesn't know how to handle this automatically - what I was getting at are the multi-step solutions provided by the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error (and warning) you see are *compilation* errors (and warning) output by a C++ compiler when compiling C code.

For instance, in C `"literal"` has type `char[]` while in C++ it has type `const char[]`.

Would you get a C++ compiler build `libopen62541.a` from `open62541.c`, you would see the same errors (warnings). But a C compiler might be OK with it (depending on the state of that C source file).

On the other hand, when you compile `my.cpp` and links it against `libopen62541.a`, the compiler doesn't see that offending C code, so no errors (warnings).

---

From here, you basically have two options:

1. Use the procompiled library if it suits you as is

   ```
   g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror my.cpp -lopen62541.a -o out
   ```
2. Compile the library's code as a first step if you need to modify it

   ```
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c open62541.c
   g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c my.cpp
   g++ open62541.o my.o -o out
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
gcc -x c++ -std=c++14 -Wall my.cpp open62541.c -lstdc++ -o out
```

This command forces the C code in `open62541.c` to be compiled as C++.  That file apparently contains constructs that are valid in C but not C++.

What you should be doing is compiling each file as its own language and then linking them together:

```
gcc -std=gnu11 -Wall -c open62541.c
g++ -std=gnu++14 -Wall -c my.cpp
g++ -o out my.o open62541.o
```

Wrapping up those commands in an easily repeatable package is what Makefiles are for.

If you're wondering why I changed from the strict `-std=c++14` to the loose `-std=gnu++14` mode, it's because the strict mode is so strict that it may break the system headers!  You don't need to deal with that on top of everything else.  If you want a more practical additional amount of strictness, try adding -Wextra and -Wpedantic instead ... but be prepared for that to throw lots of warnings that don't actually indicate bugs, on the third-party code.